# Anyone knows how to integrate flutter-deriv-api in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Anyone knows how to integrate flutter-deriv-api in flutter?
I am not getting any example code.

Below is the git repo provided by them:
https://github.com/deriv-com/flutter-deriv-api

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The repo has a path called "example" https://github.com/deriv-com/flutter-deriv-api/tree/master/example

The readme states that this shows how to integrate it.

> Demonstrates how to use the flutter_deriv_api plugin.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Not exactly. Getting Exception:
Connection to 'https://frontend.binaryws.com:0/websockets/v3?app_id=com.example.deriv_app&l=en&brand=binary#' was not upgraded to websocket.

Comment: I would suggest opening a github issue if the demo files are not working